# Adding click event using JQuery .on() function fires for every item in list

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, event-handling, jquery-events

I have a button that when clicked dynamically inserts a new row into a table.  I want to be able to remove rows from this table, so I'm trying to use jQuery's `.on()` function to attach a click handler to a span element at the end of each row.... which works fine, except that when I click on the span to remove a single item, the click event is called for all items in the table.... and they're all removed.  How do I hook it up so it calls just the row I clicked on handler?  Here is my code:

Here is the js:

```
$("#milestonesList").on('click', 'span[id*="tempmilestone"]', function (e) {
        $(this).each(function () {
            $('span[id*="tempmilestone"]').each(function () {
                alert("ON: " + $(this).attr("idx"));
                _milestones = _milestones.slice(parseInt($(this).attr("idx"), 10));
                buildMilestoneOutput(milestonesList);
            });
        });
    });
```

Now no matter what row I click on, every row's click event is fired.  What am I doing wrong?

I have tried this numerous ways, without the `.each()` functions and still it fires for every row in the table.  Maybe if I show the rest of the code it would help:

Here is the `buildMilestoneOutput` function that gets called at the end:

```
function buildMilestoneOutput(container) {
    container.innerHTML = "";
    alert("Length: " + _milestones.length);
    var s = "<table id='testscroll' style='width: 690px; padding: 10px;'><tr><td style='font-weight: bold;'>Title</td><td style='font-weight: bold;'>Description</td><td style='font-weight: bold;'>DueDate</td></tr>"
    for (var i = 0; i < _milestones.length; i++) {
        s += "<tr><td style='width: 300px; padding-bottom: 10px;'>" + _milestones[i].Title + "</td><td style='width: 350px; padding-bottom: 10px;'>" + _milestones[i].Description + "</td><td style='width: 30px; padding-bottom: 10px;'>" + _milestones[i].Name + "</td><td><span idx='" + i + "' style='margin-left: 5px; cursor: pointer;'  id='tempmilestone'>remove</span></td></tr>";
    }
    s += "</table>";
    container.innerHTML = s;
}
```

this original gets called when a user clicks an Add Milestone button:

```
$("#lbAddMilestone").click(function () {
       
        milestonesList.innerHTML = "";
        var newMilestone = new GoalMilestone();
        newMilestone.Title = "New Milestone";
        _milestones.push(newMilestone);
        buildMilestoneOutput(milestonesList);
        wireupMilestoneDeletes();
        
        return false;
    });
```

And here is the `wireupMilestoneDeletes`:

```
function wireupMilestoneDeletes() {


    $("#milestonesList").on('click', 'span[id*="tempmilestone"]', function (e) {
        alert("ON: " + $(this).attr("idx"));
        _milestones = _milestones.slice(parseInt($(this).attr("idx"), 10));
        buildMilestoneOutput(milestonesList);
    });
}
```

Comment: I would remove lines 2,3,7,8 from that code.

Comment: @Batman true, i didn,t even noticed second `each`

Comment: Basically your code says: "If a click happens in one of the items, loop through all the items and run this code for each of them", when you intended it to say: "If a click happens run this code for the specific item clicked" -> drop the `each`s, `$(this)` already holds the item clicked.

Comment: You have multiple `<span>` elements with the same id because of `<span idx='" + i + "' style='margin-left: 5px; cursor: pointer;'  id='tempmilestone'>` which can cause all sort of mumbo-jumbo. Try editing so it is `id='tempmilestone"+i+"'`, then you increment the id and the selector with `[id*='tempmilestone']` should still work

Comment: Ok...so you're saying the only change I should have to make is to make the span id unique?  The wireupMIlestoneDeletes() function above should be fine as is and only fire the span that was clicked..right?

Comment: Yes, with emphasis on _should_ :) at least, if the problem persists, we know what's not causing it

Comment: lol...well, then we know what's not causing it.  The behavior is the same.  This is very strange, as I'm doing something extremely similar with a list of textboxes and hooking up the change event via .on() and it works great....I don't understand what's happening....

Comment: It's like every time I add a new milestone, it adds another click event handler to each row.  In the alert I see the row id I clicked, as I should, only I see an alert for each row in the table.  So, if I click on the 2nd row out of 4, I'll have an alert that shows me the 2nd row's value four times....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok...so I figured it out.  I moved the wireupMilestonesDelete() function outside of the AddButton click event, to just underneath the $(document).ready function and it's now working.  I was adding a new click event to each row, after each new row insertion.  Glad that's over! :)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need an each loop, let alone two. You're binding the click event to any of the `<span>`s that have an `id` containing `"tempmilestone"` and running the handler for the click of the *specific* `<span>` that was clicked. Therefore, this should suffice:

```
$("#milestonesList").on('click', 'span[id*="tempmilestone"]', function (e) {
    alert("ON: " + $(this).attr("idx"));
    _milestones = _milestones.slice(parseInt($(this).attr("idx"), 10));
    buildMilestoneOutput(milestonesList);
});
```

Comment: That code does the exact same thing....I'm getting an alert for each row in the table with that rows idx value showing up....

Comment: check out my latest comment on the question, it might help

Answer (score 0):

You are using double each loop that doesn't make sense here. At least, not something i understand...

Try this instead:

```
$("#milestonesList").on('click', 'span[id*="tempmilestone"]', function(e) {
    $(this).each(function() {       
            alert("ON: " + $(this).attr("idx"));
               //(.......)    
    });
});​
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TJwXU/1/)